# Restart a for loop after the end of an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I working in JavaScript and am trying to add some images to a site.

I have a list of blog posts on a page. And I have a bunch of small stand-alone images (think small icon images) that I want to place on either side of the blog post feed. They are kind of just like random background images. As the feed gets longer, more images will automatically be placed.

Here is some example code of what I have so far. Right now I am just appending text to the page to get this working.

I need help figuring out how to restart this loop once the end of the array is reached. For example, after 6url.jpg is printed, I want to print 1url.jpg and so on if my imageCount is more than 6. I played around with continue and while loops but not sure how to implement that.

```
var blogIcons = ["1url.jpg", "2url.jpg", "3url.jpg", "4url.jpg", "5url.jpg", "6url.jpg"];
var blogFeedHeight = $(".blog-feed").height();
var imageDistance = 400; 
// Determining how many images to place based on the blog feed height;
var imageCount = Math.ceil(blogFeedHeight/imageDistance); 
// the number of images that should be inserted.
for(var i = 0; i < imageCount; i++){
    $('blog-feed').append('<div class="blog-icon">' + blogIcons[i] +'</div>')
}
```

Comment: till when do you want to continue ?

Comment: When will you break the loop?

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is called modulo, the rest of the euclidian division of 2 numbers.

```js
var blogIcons = ["1url.jpg", "2url.jpg", "3url.jpg", "4url.jpg", "5url.jpg", "6url.jpg"];
var imageCount = 10;
// the number of images that should be inserted.
for (var i = 0; i < imageCount; i++) {
  console.log(blogIcons[i % blogIcons.length])
}
```

I simplified your problem so it can run on StackOverflow. but you'll get the proper index by using "%"

So your script should look like that:

```
var blogIcons = ["1url.jpg", "2url.jpg", "3url.jpg", "4url.jpg", "5url.jpg", "6url.jpg"];
var blogFeedHeight = $(".blog-feed").height();
var imageDistance = 400; 
// Determining how many images to place based on the blog feed height;
var imageCount = Math.ceil(blogFeedHeight/imageDistance); 
// the number of images that should be inserted.
for(var i = 0; i < imageCount; i++){
    $('blog-feed').append('<div class="blog-icon">' + blogIcons[i % blogIcons.length] +'</div>')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to *restart* a loop. Instead you can use modulo division to fetch an item within bounds from the array

```js
var blogIcons = ["1url.jpg", "2url.jpg", "3url.jpg", "4url.jpg", "5url.jpg", "6url.jpg"];

for (var i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
  console.log(blogIcons[i % blogIcons.length]);
}
```

When doing `i % blogIcons.length` you will get a number between `0` and `blogIcons.length`

Comment: I'd appreciate feedback on what is wrong with this answer.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your answer so I +1 to even it out. Maybe people downvoted because you didn't use all the original code. I don't know.